# Initialize and accessing 2D matrix pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, initialization

I'm new in C++ and I try to get the "pointer mindset" to code with efficiency.

I'm trying to code *el famoso* Game of Life. So, I need a 2D matrix. Since it will be modify at each epoch (regarding the GoL rules), I would like to declare this matrix as a pointer to be able to point on it each time a cell evolves (and prevents rewriting).

I understood that I need to declare a `vector` of `vector<int>`. I proceed like this :

```cpp
int i_size(50);
int j_size(50);
vector<int> arr(j_size, 0);
vector<vector<int>> *matrix;
matrix = new vector<vector<int>>;
    
for (int i(0); i<i_size; i++)
{
    matrix->push_back(arr);
}
```

Here, I hope to get a pointer `matrix` which point to a `vector` of `vector` well allocated and initialized at `0`.

**At this point, I'm stuck.**

I know how to print the memory address of my matrix (`cout << matrix`).
I know how to print the memory address of each vector contained in matrix (`cout << &matrix[i]`)

And that's all.

### Questions

- Is my matrix declaration/initialization correct ?
- How can I access to my matrix ?
- How can I modify one cell of my matrix ?

Thanx all for your help. Again, I'm beginner so any advice will be helpful ! :)

Comment: "I try to get the "pointer mindset" to code with efficiency." ... frankly, this sounds like cargo-cult. Using more pointers does not imply more efficiency.

Comment: frankly, using a pointer to a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is totally misguided. You gain nothing by dynamically allocating the vector here. `std::vector` does already manage its dynamically allocated memory for you

Comment: Just use `int Matrix[50][50]` if the size is constant.

Comment: @fana No! In such case `std::array<std::array<int,50>,50>` should be used.

Comment: Catch the first bus that goes out of the "pointer mindset". You don't want to be there, and you don't want to listen to people who sent you there ever again.

Comment: What version of the C++ you can use? C++23 has some cool library  features which makes this simple: [std::mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Why "should be used" ?
If `int Matrix[50][50]` is perfectly enough (if don't need what `std::array` provides), this is the simplest/easiest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct, but unecessarily complicated. You gain nothing by dynamically allocating the vector, because `std::vector` does already manage its elements dynamically.

Once you are settled with using a nested vector (*), the simple version of your code is this:

```
int i_size(50);
int j_size(50);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix{ std::vector<int>(j_size),i_size};
```

Using more pointers does not imply more performance, but most of the time it implies more bugs and more complicated code. There is no "pointer mindset" that would lead to efficiency.

(*) What probably would gain you performance would be to use a flat 1D vector with index transformations. The big plus of a vector is its memory locality, but as the vector dynamically allocates an array to store the elements, the inner elements are not contigous in a nested vector. Alternatively consider to use `std::array` (which has no issue with nesting). When you do care about performance you must profile and measure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your implementation is correct, as a matrix is created with the right size and you can access the value of the matrix with this syntax

```
(*matrix)[i][j]
```

In the same way you can modify the value of each element of the matrix by

```
(*matrix)[i][j]=value;
```

However, the use of a pointer doesn't increase the efficiency of your program in this case. Vector already take care of the dynamic memory allocation and deallocation.
By the way there is a more efficient way to declare the matrix with vector which would be

```
vector<vector<int>> matrix(i_size, vector<int>(j_size, 0));
```

I believe pointers are better use for arrays, so for exemple if you were to write your code like this.

```
int** matrix = new int*[i_size];
for (int i = 0; i < i_size; i++) {
    matrix[i] = new int[j_size]{};
}
```

Finally, if your goal is to code the game of life , I would like to point out that there is only two state for each sqaure so try to use bool instead of int

Comment: If anything, a matrix class should just keep a single, contiguous array of the held type (e.g. `std::vector <int>`) as private member variable, and provide functions for arbitrary access of rows and cells. The `[]` operator overloading won't fit well for that though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It fits perfectly well in C++23 and up.

Comment: I wasn't aware this was to be a part of a class, if it is yeah having a simple vector<int> is probably better.
I was under the impression this was a code directly put in the main, so I did a vector<vector<int>> to simplify the access of each square. In my experience trying to know which case to call in the game with an array instead of a matrix is a little hard and make the code harder to read.

Comment: Well, it's a question of memory efficiency (and a bit of performance also).

Comment: "I believe pointers are better use for arrays" why?

Comment: I wanted to give an exemple where using pointers would make sens, because at least with arrays you can dynamically change the size of the array, where using them for vector is pointless. I was not saying that he had to use pointers for arrays, sorry.